# Involution and Gelfand Transform Properties

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a commutative unital Banach algebra, and let for each $x\in\mathcal{B}$ $\hat{x}$ be the Gelfand transform. I assume that $\mathcal{B}$ has an involution *.

I want to show that:

> 1) $\|\hat{x}\|=\|\hat{x^*}\|$;
>
> 2) if $x=x^*$, then $\|x\|=\|\hat{x}\|$;
>
> 3) if $\|x^*x\|=\|x^*\|\|x\|$ for each $x\in\mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{B}$ is a $C^*$-algebra.

I observe that 
\begin{align}
\|\hat{x}\|&=\sup_{\varphi}|{\hat{x}(\varphi)}|\\
           &=\sup_{\varphi}|{\varphi(x)}|\\
           &=\sup_{\varphi}|{\overline{\varphi(x)}}|\\
           &=\sup_{\varphi}|{\varphi(x^*)}|\\
           &=\sup_{\varphi}|{\hat{x^*}(\varphi)}|=\|\hat{x^*}\|\\
\end{align}

Now, I assume that $x$ is self-adjoint, i.e. $x=x^*$. There are proofs where the C* property is used, i.e. $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2$ to show that Gelfand representations are isometric. However, I want to show that self-adjointness is enough. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to do this.

Next, we see that $\mathcal{B}$ is a commutative unitial Banach algebra. So, the only thing I need to show here is that 
$$
\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2
$$
holds. In other words, I need to show that $\|x^*x\|=\|x^*\|\|x\|$ implies $\|x^*x\|=\|x\|^2$. Here, I considered $x=u^*u$, but it wasn't very helpful.

Can anyone help me? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If all you assume about your involution is that it's an involution. that is, $(x+y)^*=x^*+y^*$, $(xy)^*=x^*y^*$, $x^{**}=x$ and $(cx)^*=\overline cx^*$, then most of what you expect doesn't follow. In particular you assume above that $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$, and *that* doesn't follow:

Consider $C([-1,1])$. Define $$f^*(t)=\overline{f(-t).}$$ That's an involution with $||f^*||=||f||$ but $\phi(f^*)\ne\overline{\phi(f)}$.

It's easy to make things worse. Define a non-standard norm on $C([-1,1])$ by $$||f||=\max(\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|f(t)|,\sup_{-1\le t<0}2|f(t)|).$$That norm makes $C([-1,1])$ into a Banach algebra isomorphic to the usual $C([-1,1])$, but the involution above has $||f^*||\ne||f||$.

---

**Bonus** Not that you asked, but on the topic of proving the basic facts about $C^*$ algebras under weaker hypotheses, you might note that it's impossible to give purely algebraic proofs of various things that look like they should be nothing but algebra.

> > **Example** A gizmo that satisfies all the properties of a $C^*$ algebra except that the norm is not complete, but such that $\phi(x^*)\ne\overline{\phi(x)}$ for every complex homomorphism $\phi$, and $x^*=x$ does not imply $\phi(x)\in\Bbb R$

Let $A$ be the algebra of trigonometric polynomials $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-N}^Na_ne^{int},$$with  pointwise operations, $||f||=\sup_{t\in\Bbb R}|f(t)|$, and the usual involution $$f^*(t)=\overline{f(t)}=\sum_{n=-N}^N\overline{a_{-n}}e^{int}.$$That satisfies all the axioms except for completeness of the norm. But if $$\phi(f)=\sum_{n=-N}^Na_n2^n$$then $\phi$ is a complex homomorphism of $A$ with $\phi(f^*)\ne\overline{\phi(f)}$. And in fact $f^*=f$ does not imply $\phi(f)\in\Bbb R$.

(A few years ago I noticed that the proof that $x^*=x$ implies $\phi(x^*)\in\Bbb R$ in a $C^*$ algebra involved completeness, and this seemed "wrong". Spent a *long* time looking for a purely algebraic proof... When I finally noticed that example I decided that from then on when I was doing $C^*$ algebra things I'd assume I had a $C^*$ algebra, heh-heh.)

---

**Edit** It appears that all this started with an [exercise](https://s32.postimg.org/c2z9jo9xh/Screenshot_from_2016_07_25_01_18_31.jpg).

Part (a) of the exercise is fine, and in fact we don't need to show that $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$ to prove it. Instead we define an involution on the maximal ideal space by $\phi^*(x)=\overline{\phi(x^*)}$, and (a) follows easily.

But part (b)  is simply false (unless the definition of "involution" in the exercise includes something we haven't beem told about).

Some authors require $||e||=1$ in the definition of Banach algebra with identity and some do not. If $||e||\ne1$ is allowed then it's clear that (b) is false: Given $A$ as in the exercise, define $$|||x|||=2||x||.$$Then $A$ is also a Banach algebra with the new norm, and (b) cannot be true of both norms (since $||\hat x||$ is independent of the choice of norm on $A$).

If $||e||=1$ is part of the definition, let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra with an involution but without an identity. Append an identity in the usual way: Let $A'=A\times\Bbb C$, define a multiplication so that $e=(0,1)$ is an identity, and define $$||(x,\lambda)||=||x||+|\lambda|.$$Consider $$|||(x,\lambda)|||=2||x||+|\lambda|.$$

Part (c) is ok, in fact the hypothesis in (c) is what is usually taken as the definition. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C*-algebra) for a conjecture regarding what the definition in the exercise might be. The equivalence of the two conditions in that Wikipedia article is a standard thing; however we prove it we'd better not use (b)...

Comment: @david-c-ullrich, I also assume that $(x+y)^*=x^*+y^*$ and $(xy)^*=y^*x^*$, however it seems like you are right. Here is a screenshot of the exercise [link](https://s32.postimg.org/c2z9jo9xh/Screenshot_from_2016_07_25_01_18_31.jpg).

Comment: @funop Overlooked those two, but no it doesn't matter. You should see the Bonus section added in an edit...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Interesting answer! However, I am a bit confused. Is it true that $\phi(x^*)=\overline{\phi(x)}$, which is related to the $C^*$-property, is  a necessary condition to prove 1,2,3 (See link first comment by funop)?

Comment: @Jan Assuming you mean (a), (b) and (c): It's not needed for (a). Define $\phi^*(x)=\overline{\phi(x^*)}$. On the other hand (b) and (c) are simply false, never mind what's needed to prove them, it can't be done, without some axiom relating the involution to the norm. See edit, to appear very soon...

Comment: @Jan Or rather part (b) is false, not (c).

Comment: @funop News: Part (b) of that exercise is actually false. (hadn't considered the exercise until Jan asked about it...)